# How to terminate users in bulk inSailPoint IIQ?

Tags: user-management, sailpoint

I have identified nearly 1K Service identities, Shared Identities, Privileged Identities. I need to clear all these identities immediately, kindly say if there is a way to do this in bulk.

Terminate/remove users in Bulk

Answer (score 0):

If you have identified the identities, then you can use the IIQ console to delete those, but take these **steps carefully on higher environments**; *Refer to the IIQ admin guide -> IIQ console section for this command*.
Also, take a backup of database before doing such activities.

`<delete Identity "name">` is the IIQ console command. If you want to delete identities in bulk, then prepare a file for e.g., `identityData.txt` and that file must contain records in the below format:

```
delete Identity identity1

delete Identity identity2

delete Identity identity3
```

And then go to the IIQ console and execute this command

```
> source identityData.txt
```

Verify your identities from the console.